# how to prevent page reload until file uploads in safari

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, safari, submit

I have loader, which works correctly in all browsers except safari
here is my code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setTimeout($.loader({className:'blue-with-image-2',content:''}),0); document.myform.submit();return false;"></a>
```

so, in all browsers everything works ok, but in safari page reloads without showing loader. I've searched a lot of information and have tried such workaround:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="setTimeout($.loader({className:'blue-with-image-2',content:''}),0); setTimeout(document.myform.submit(), 200);return false;"></a>
```

but it is unsuitable, because, f.e. in IE loader rotates only for 200ms (it's like a half of circle), so setting timeout for some seconds makes loader rotate for some time, but it's unsuitable(what if user would want to upload 500mb file and loader would rotate just for 2 seconds and then wait until page reloads).
So I need a working solution to work in all browsers.

Comment: I don't see anything about jQuery mentioned in the OP; edited tags. Thanks.

Comment: loader is jQuery plugin

Comment: It's important to mention such critical details in the OP along with a relevant link to the plugin's website so the reader knows exactly what you're talking about.  Thanks.

Comment: point your form to a hidden iframe and define an  onload() event on that frame that then reloads the main page once the file upload is complete; not before or after, but perfectly on-time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using timeouts to coordinate asynchronous processes which is a bad idea. You cannot sync asynchronous components by means of artifical timeouts.

One way to get rid of the timeouts is to use the [`FileReader` Interface of the Html5 FileAPI](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader). That way you can specifically handle the start and end of an upload operation without having to rely on `setTimeout`.

Ideally you would then start to show the loader just before the upload operation and hide the loader in either the success or the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

If not wrong, you are trying to submit the form using the anchor click. And wanted to show the loader until file uploading is done. I have observed that you are using jquery already in your page. So why can't you just add a event listener on the anchor element (root which is mentioned in the example) and add two functions 
1. showing loader,
2. (later)submitting the form inside it , by adding another check which is waiting for the upload event to be fired.

So to be more elaborative, when the user clicks on anchor it shows the loader and you will add a eventlistener for the fileupload you can refer this documentation https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options and once the event is done you can fire the submit event on the form.